# MPI in c. Using Loop in I_send and Irecv

Tags: c, mpi

I have a simple code of MPI in c where i try to learn how to communicate between processes. This is the code:

**EDITED CODE -> PROBLEM SOLVED**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ONE 0
#define TWO 1

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int dimension = 5,t;
    float ** matrix;
    float * mat1;
    float * mat2,*mat;
    int i,j,numNeighbor, processReceived,rank,size,retval;
    int k = 0;
    retval = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Request sendRequest[2], recvRequest[2];
    MPI_Status status[2];//osa kai auta pou perimenw apo to receive
    MPI_Datatype row;

    MPI_Type_vector(dimension, 1, dimension, MPI_FLOAT, &row);
    MPI_Type_commit(&row);

    if(retval != MPI_SUCCESS)
    {
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, retval);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    mat1 = malloc(dimension*sizeof(float));
    mat2 = malloc(dimension*sizeof(float));
    matrix = malloc(dimension*sizeof(float*));
    mat = malloc(dimension*dimension*sizeof(float));

    for(i=0; i<dimension; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = mat + i*dimension;
    }

    printf("MATRIX OF RANK %d\n", rank);
    for(i=0; i<dimension; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<dimension; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = (float)(rank+1)*(i*2+j);
            printf("%2.1f ",matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(t=0; t<10; t++) //<----------------------PROBLEM WITH THIS LOOP
    {
        MPI_Isend(&(matrix[0][0]), 1, row, 1-rank, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, sendRequest + ONE);
        MPI_Isend(&(matrix[0][0]), dimension, MPI_FLOAT, 1-rank, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, sendRequest + TWO);

        MPI_Irecv(mat1,dimension, MPI_FLOAT, 1-rank, 1-rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, recvRequest + ONE);
        MPI_Irecv(mat2,dimension, MPI_FLOAT, 1-rank, 1-rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, recvRequest + TWO);


        for(i=0; i<2; i++)
        {
            MPI_Waitany(2,recvRequest, &processReceived, status);
            printf("Process Received : %d of rank : %d\n", processReceived,rank);
            if(processReceived == ONE)
            {
                printf("%d ",rank);
                for(j=0; j<dimension; j++)  printf("# %6.1f ",mat1[j]);
                printf("\n");
            }

            if(processReceived == TWO)
            {
                printf("%d ",rank);
                for(j=0; j<dimension; j++)  printf("@ %6.1f ",mat2[j]);
                printf("\n");
            }
        }

        MPI_Waitall(2, sendRequest, status);
        MPI_Type_free(&row);            
    }
    free(mat1);
    free(mat2);
    free(mat);
    free(matrix);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I execute this program without the loop with the big arrow `for(t=0; t<10; t++)` and everything is fine. When I use the loop it runs well for the first time and then this error message appears:

> Fatal error in PMPI_Isend: Invalid datatype, error stack:
>   PMPI_Isend(149): MPI_Isend(buf=(nil), count=1, MPI_DATATYPE_NULL,
>   dest=1, tag=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, request=0xbf8764b8) failed
>   PMPI_Isend(102): Datatype for argument datatype is a null datatype
>   Fatal error in PMPI_Isend: Invalid datatype, error stack:
>   PMPI_Isend(149): MPI_Isend(buf=(nil), count=1, MPI_DATATYPE_NULL,
>   dest=0, tag=1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, request=0xbf8e8e18) failed
>   PMPI_Isend(102): Datatype for argument datatype is a null datatype

I assume that I have somehow to reinitialize my sends, recvs and maybe statuses. Is my assumption correct? If yes, how can I solve this? If no, can you see any problem?

This is the whole program so you can execute it by yourselves

```
mpiexec -n 2 ./name_exe
```

**It runs only with 2 processes!!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your `for` loop, you use `MPI_Type_free(&row);`, after which `row` is no longer a registered `MPI_Type`, so your first `MPI_Isend` is using an invalid datatype (as the error suggests). Move this line to outside the `for` loop. You're also freeing `matrix`, which means in the second iteration, your are trying to send memory that you no longer own, which should produce a seg-fault.

Comment: Well that is correct but even after this correction i have the same error at the same moment.

Comment: @dimitrisdiamond: After the correction you get an invalid datatype error on the second iteration of the loop, but not the first? Unless you're changing `row` somewhere where I'm just not seeing it, you should at least get a different error.

Comment: Give me a moment to check something.

Comment: @dimitrisdiamond: Looking a little bit further, you are also `free`-ing the memory you are trying to send; the second send is of a pointer that points to memory you no longer own which will cause all sorts of issues.

Comment: Yeah i just saw that. So I used thes corrections: I initialize row every time in the loop and I free it, I free my structures outside the loop and now everything is fine. Thanks for the help!